# Пропадает подключение к локальному серверу

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер, ktor

У меня развернут локальный сервер на android устройстве (ktor) (`http://192.168.31.250:8080/`). В качестве клиента я использую windows и mac и рандомно сервер просто "падает" на клиенте (`ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` или просто зависает).

1 кейс - если зайти из под того же андроида (где запущен сервер то он работает) а на клиенте по прежнему нет.

2 кейс - если зайти на 2м клиенте то сервер так же работает и при этом он оживает на 1м клиенте.

3 кейс - сервер падает на обоих клиентах и работает только на андроиде.

Думал что причина в бездействии но нет, перезапуск не помогает, так же сделал сокет который раз в 10сек отправляет статус сервера - то же самое (бывает просто виснет).
Спустя N время он опять работает там где завис. Иногда помогает (иногда нет) смена на https или очистка dns кеша.

Может что то связанное с защитой на роутере или еще где? или какие headers нужны?
отдаю `Connection: keep-alive` и `Cache-Control: private`